# Unable to get compass watch to work

Tags: sass, compass

I'm afraid I can't give much more information than the stack trace.  I'm trying to get compass to work locally; I am using Sass 3.4.22 and Compass 1.0.3.  Some other answers suggest some combinations may not work, but I couldn't find anything one way or the other with those versions.  I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling both of them.

Here's the output for `compass watch --trace`:

```
LoadError on line ["55"] of /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb: cannot load such file -- compass-h5bp
  /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/data.rb:179:in `require'
  /Users/paulnicholsen/industry/divesite-docker/socialmediatoday/sites/all/themes/smtrelaunch/config.rb:2:in `get_binding'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `eval'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:24:in `parse_string'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:15:in `block in _parse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `open'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/serialization.rb:14:in `_parse'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:7:in `block in new_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-core-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/inheritance.rb:207:in `with_defaults'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/file_data.rb:6:in `new_from_file'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:19:in `configuration_for'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/configuration/helpers.rb:69:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:37:in `add_project_configuration'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:25:in `configure!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:15:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:41:in `initialize'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `new'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:42:in `perform!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `call'
  /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/bin/compass:23:in `load'
  /usr/local/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently `compass-h5bp` is a separate package.  `gem install compass-h5bp` made the error change to a different package, and I'm going through one-by-one installing them.  If there's a better method/answer, have at it!